# How to get datetime data in database?

Tags: c#, sql-server, datetime

I'm trying to get date from SQL Server to C#. I couldn't do that.

I can't get the date. I just need the date information like `MM/DD/YY`, not like `06/26/2009 00:00:00:000`, I don't need the time information.

When I try this command text in SQL Server, it works.

When I try this code, at the

```
date = drr["Tarih"].toString();
```

part, I get an error

> System.IndexOutOfRangeException

Code:

```
SqlConnection con;
SqlCommand cmd;
string date;

public string getDate(int noo, int idd)
{
        int no = noo;
        int id = idd;

        con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=AHMET\SQLEXPRESS; Initial Catalog=yoklama; Integrated Security=True");

        cmd = new SqlCommand();

        cmd.Connection = con;
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        cmd.CommandText = "Select Max(Tarih) from Yoklama where Ogrenci_NO = '" + no + "' and Ders_ID = '" + id + "' ";

        try
        {
            con.Open();

            SqlDataReader drr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

            while(dr.Read()) { 
                date = drr["Tarih"].ToString();
            }
        }
        catch (SqlException)
        {
            // error here
        }
        finally
        {
            con.Close();
        }

        return date;
}
```

Comment: This is messed up.   There return type is int.   Does tarih = dr["Tarih"]; even work?  I don't see where you even open the connection.  Fix the formatting.

Comment: that was my bad, i tried a lot of things, i forget to fix it

Comment: Then fix the question.  And fix the formatting.  Answer is only as good as the question.  This is likely to get shut down if you don't fix the question.

Comment: @Paparazzi i fixed the question

Comment: [SQL Injection alert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms161953%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) - you should **not** concatenate together your SQL statements - use **parametrized queries** instead to avoid SQL injection

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> System.IndexOutOfRangeException

This assumes that there is a column named `Tarih`:

```
drr["Tarih"]
```

But there isn't.  Look closely at the query:

```
Select Max(Tarih) from Yoklama ...
```

The query *uses* that column, but doesn't actually *produce* that column.  It produces a calculated column which is going to have some default name.

You can specify a name for that column in the query:

```
Select Max(Tarih) AS Tarih from Yoklama ...
```

or perhaps just select the first (and basically only) column in the results:

```
drr[0]
```

Comment: it doesn't work, i don't know why.. there is no date data

Comment: @Ahmet: In what way does it fail?  What does the actual SQL query return?  What is in `dr["Tarih"]`?  Does `dr` contain any rows at all?  "It doesn't work" isn't really a description of a problem.

Comment: i fixed the question

Comment: Thank you sir ! it works now. i wanna kiss your hand, in Turkey if you respect to someone, you kiss him hand :) i was trying to fix this for 2-3 hours. This is my first time i used max() , that is why i couldn't fix it

Comment: @Ahmet: Glad I could help!  (And hand-kissing isn't entirely necessary on Stack Overflow.  We're happy just to be of service here.)